# showing animation of poly-lines in googlemap based on user selection in drop-down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I have created an application for animating the poly-line in google-maps, the animation will start once we select a particular user from the drop-down, The application is working fine but the issue is that, once a particular animation is started and under proceeding if we select another user the application is getting hanged and showing unexpected animations,

can anyone please tell me some solution for breaking a animation in between once another user is selected and need to show the selected user poly-line animation after that

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CHlCbA5eKEdpYMde5bS8?p=preview)**

```
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@2.4.1" data-semver="2.4.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=panoramio"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">

  <select ng-change="showGPSTracking()" ng-model="user">
    <option selected="selected" value="" class="">Select User</option>
    <option value="1458">1458</option>
    <option value="1658">1658</option>
  </select>
  </br></br></br></br>
    <div style="width: 880px;">
      <div id="map" style="width: 880px; height: 500px; float: left;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your Plunkr url just seems to be timing out for me right now... it may be temporamental, but you'd still be better adding your javascript to your question

Comment: @duncan is there any issues with my plunker, since because of length I have included the js within my question....you can see there within my plunker

Answer (score 1):

The problem you had was you had a single global `map` variable.  Each time you change user, you update that map and create hundreds of function calls.  So those function calls on the first map start conflicting with those on the second map - they're all working on the same map object.

My quick and dirty fix here is simply to make the map object a local variable, and pass it into the `autoRefresh` function.  The calls to the functions on the first map will still be happening, just the result won't be visible as you've essentially hidden that map when you re-assigned the map div to the new map.

It's not ideal I think, but it seems to work for me.  Ideally you'd have some way of 'stopping' the animation on one of the maps, and preventing all the functions adding to the route from being executed.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http, item) {
  $scope.tracker = {};
  var items;
  $scope.showLiveMap = false;
  $scope.showLiveMap = false;
  var firtslat, firstlong;

  var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png");
  var center = null;
  //var map = null;  - you don't need this any more
  var currentPopup;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var markLAT, markLNG, trackId;
  var marker;

  function moveMarker(map, marker, lat, lon) {
    try {
      marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon));
      map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon));

    } catch (e) {}
  }

  $scope.autoRefresh = function(map) {
    try {
      var route = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: [],
              geodesic : true,
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              editable: false,
              map:map
            }),
            index=0,
            marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:map,icon:icon});

      if (!_.isEmpty(items)) {
        angular.forEach(items, function(cordinates) {
          setTimeout(function ()
          {         
            route.getPath().push(new google.maps.LatLng(cordinates.lat, cordinates.lng));

           // route.setMap(map);  not necessary, you set the map when you created the route
            moveMarker(map, marker, cordinates.lat, cordinates.lng);
            markLAT = cordinates.lat;
            markLNG = cordinates.lng;
          }, 200*++index);
        });  
      }
      //  
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e); 
    }
  }; 

function initMap(user)
{
  items = item.items[user];
  try {
    markLAT = items[items.length - 1].lat;
    markLNG = items[items.length - 1].lng;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(markLAT, markLNG),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
      }, 
      navigationControl: true,
      navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
      }
    });
    $scope.autoRefresh(map); // passed the local map variable into the function
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

  $scope.showGPSTracking = function() {
    if (!_.isNull($scope.user)) {
      initMap($scope.user);
    } else {
      console.log("entered");
      $scope.showLiveMap = false;
    }
  };
});
```